# Binding an element of a list to a Label

Tags: java, javafx, observer-pattern

I have a problem when I try to bind an element of a list to a JavaFX Label.
I don't have the problem if the item is not in a list.

Is the GarbageCollector the reason for this problem?

Controller.class : (controller of the fxml file)

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
  private final Context context = Context.getInstance();
  private List<Label> labels;

  public void initialize() {
    labels = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < context.getComponents().get(i).size(); i++) {
      labels.add(new Label(context.getComponent().get(i).toString()));
      
      labels.get(i).textProperty().bind(context.getComponents().get(i));

      gridPane.add(labels.get(i), 0, i); // The GridPane on the FXML
    }
  }
}
```

Context.java : (class where the variables are refreshed)

```
public final class Context implements StatusEventListener, MssEventListener {
  private final List<StringProperty> components;
  
  public static Context getInstance() {
    return SingletonHandler.instance;
  }

  private Context() {
    super();
    components = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String component : new InstallProgress().getListInstallingItem()) {
      components.add(new SimpleStringProperty(component));
    }
  }

  public List<StringProperty> getComponents() {
    return components;
  }

  // Reset the list
  public void setComponents(final List<String> components) {
    this.components.clear();
    for (String component : components) {
      this.components.add(new SimpleStringProperty(component));
    }
  }

  private static class SingletonHandler {
        private static final Context instance = new Context();
        
        private SingletonHandler() {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

To refresh the label, I use `Context.setComponents(<myUpdatedList>)` but nothing happens...

If I refresh a `StringProperty component` on Context.java, the display shows the new value of that variable.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The ith label's text is bound to the ith `StringProperty` in the context. When you replace the entire list in the context, the label's text is still bound to the old `StringProperty` object (you don't change the binding). Instead of replacing the elements of `components`, it may be enough to update each one's value (just call `set(...)` on each one). Is it guaranteed that the list passed to `setComponents(...)` is the same size as the current `components`? If not, what do you want to happen in that scenario?

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't just want to use a `ListView` here?

Comment: As an aside, the singleton pattern is widely considered to be an anti-pattern. I recommend using some form of dependency injection (not necessarily a DI framework, just pass the correct `Context` instance to whatever objects need it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindings bind the text of each label to the corresponding `StringProperty` in the context (model). If you replace the entire `StringProperty` in the context, the label's text is still bound to the old `StringProperty`, not the one that replaced it (you don't update the binding).

(If you don't keep a reference anywhere to the old `StringProperty`, it will be eligible for garbage collection. Bindings use weak listeners (which in turn use weak references to the object they are observing) and so your bindings don't prevent the `StringProperty` from being garbage collected. This isn't the cause of the problem, though; the issue is simply that your label's text is not bound to the new `StringProperty` you create in the `setComponents(...)` method.)

Your best option here is to use an `ObservableList<String>` in the model class:

```
public final class Context implements StatusEventListener, MssEventListener {
  private final ObservableList<String> components;
  
  public static Context getInstance() {
    return SingletonHandler.instance;
  }

  private Context() {
    super();
    components = FXCollections.observableArrayList<>(new InstallProgress().getListInstallingItem());

  }

  public ObservableList<String> getComponents() {
    return components;
  }

  // Reset the list
  public void setComponents(final List<String> components) {
    this.components.setAll(components);
  }

  private static class SingletonHandler {
        private static final Context instance = new Context();
        
        private SingletonHandler() {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

And now your view class can just observe the list. I added handling here for the list changing size, which your original code didn't support:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
  private final Context context = Context.getInstance();
  private List<Label> labels;

  public void initialize() {
    labels = new ArrayList<>();
    
    updateLabelsFromContext();
    context.getComponents().addListener((Change<? extends String> c) ->
      updateLabelsFromContext());
  }

  private void updateLabelsFromContext() {
    List<String> components = context.getComponents();
    for (int i=0; i < labels.size() && i < components.size(); i++) {
      labels.get(i).setText(components.get(i));
    }

    // remove excess labels:
    
    for (int i=components.size(); i<labels.size(); i++) {
      gridPane.getChildren().remove(labels.get(i));
    }
    if (components.size() < labels.size()) {
      labels.subList(components.size(), labels.size()).clear();
    }

    // add any new labels needed:    
    for (int i = labels.size(); i<components.size(); i++) {
      Label label = new Label(components.get(i));
      labels.add(label);
      gridPane.add(label, 0, i);
    }
  }
}
```

If it's guaranteed the size of the list in the context is always the same, you can do

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
  private final Context context = Context.getInstance();
  private List<Label> labels; // may not be needed

  public void initialize() {
    labels = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<context.getComponents().size(); i++) {
      Label label = new Label();
      labels.add(label); // may not be needed
      label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.valueAt(context.getComponents(),i);
      gridPane.add(label, 0, i);
    }        
    
  }


}
```

Comment: I put the code in the ```getComponents()``` method in a thread, otherwise I had an IllegalStateException